Specify exogenous regressors conditionally for each series in ARIMA?
Q: In the context of forecasting many series with exogenous regressors in the R tidyverts/fable framework, is there a tidy way to tell fable::ARIMA() that I want it to estimate, e.g., y~x1+x2 for series aa, y~x2 for series bb, and y~x1 for series cc?
Note: I actually care about the general case where there are many series, many exogenous regressors, and many unique combinations of exogenous regressors desired over the many series.
This is related to my question. Run ARIMA without xreg when they're completely rank deficient?. There, more specifically, I ask if there's simply a way to tell ARIMA() to fail over to running ARIMA(y) when exogenous regressors are completely rank deficient. But here, I'm asking about the more general case.
Below, I include the same minimal working example as I did in my previous question. But here, my attention is on the final block of code, where I basically specify a different tibble to be used as data for each series. I could, e.g., for series aa,  just pull out its data table as data and run data %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~x1+x2)). But, again, I'm trying to handle the general case, in a tidy way. Is there such a way?
I really just don't know how to run the last mile on this. I'd like to approach this in a tidy way, which I figure involves some combo of rlang, !!, !!!, quo, new_formula, etc. But these packages and functions still confuse me and I've been looking at this for too long. I'm calling a lifeline.
set.seed(123)

# create data
tibble(idx=1:12,group='aa',y=rnorm(12)) -> aa
tibble(idx=7:12,group='bb',y=rnorm(6)) -> bb
tibble(idx=1:6,group='cc',y=rnorm(6)) -> cc
tibble(idx=1:12,
       x1=c(0,0,1,rep(0,9)),
       x2=c(rep(0,9),1,0,0)) -> xreg
bind_rows(aa,bb,cc) %>% 
  inner_join(xreg,by='idx') %>% 
  as_tsibble(index=idx,key=group) -> dat
dat %>% print(n=Inf)
# # A tsibble: 24 x 5 [1]
# # Key:       group [3]
# idx group       y    x1    x2
# <int> <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 aa     1.15       0     0
# 2     2 aa    -0.231      0     0
# 3     3 aa    -0.365      1     0
# 4     4 aa     0.158      0     0
# 5     5 aa     0.766      0     0
# 6     6 aa     0.426      0     0
# 7     7 aa     0.927      0     0
# 8     8 aa     0.0461     0     0
# 9     9 aa    -0.504      0     0
# 10    10 aa    -0.300      0     1
# 11    11 aa     0.823      0     0
# 12    12 aa    -0.849      0     0
# 13     7 bb    -0.954      0     0
# 14     8 bb     0.313      0     0
# 15     9 bb     0.612      0     0
# 16    10 bb    -1.69       0     1
# 17    11 bb     0.785      0     0
# 18    12 bb     0.0119     0     0
# 19     1 cc    -0.181      0     0
# 20     2 cc     1.11       0     0
# 21     3 cc     1.48       1     0
# 22     4 cc    -1.15       0     0
# 23     5 cc     1.01       0     0
# 24     6 cc    -0.632      0     0

# Everything as I'd expect. No problem here. 
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y)) -> fit.y
fit.y
# # A mable: 3 x 2
# # Key:     group [3]
# group          arima
# <chr>        <model>
#   1 aa    <ARIMA(0,0,0)>
#   2 bb    <ARIMA(0,0,0)>
#   3 cc    <ARIMA(0,0,0)>

# Still, everything as I'd expect. Just a warning message which follows. 
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~x1+x2)) -> fit.yx1x2
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y,xreg=dat%>%select(x1,x2))) -> fit.yx1x2
# Warning messages:
# 1: Provided exogenous regressors are rank deficient, removing regressors: `x1` 
# 2: Provided exogenous regressors are rank deficient, removing regressors: `x2` 

# For group bb, x1 dropped and x2 retained, as I'd expect
# For group cc, x2 dropped and x1 retained, as I'd expect
fit.yx1x2 %>% pull(arima) %>% map(c('fit', 'par'))
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 2 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 x1       1.56      0.777     2.01   0.0679
# 2 x2      -0.446     0.777    -0.574  0.577 
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 x2        1.79     0.875      2.04  0.0873
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 x1       -1.07     0.625     -1.71   0.139

# Now there's an error. I was surprised by this. 
# Sure, for group bb, x1 is just a column of zeros. 
# But if it's removed shouldn't the model estimated by the same as the one as
# if I had specified `ARIMA(y)`, as above, as if `x1` had never been mentioned?
dat %>% model(arima=ARIMA(y~x1)) -> fit.yx1
# Warning messages:
# 1: Provided exogenous regressors are rank deficient, removing regressors: `x1` 
# 2: 1 error encountered for arima
# [1] subscript out of bounds

# A NULL model is estimated for group bb, rather than `<ARIMA(0,0,0)>` as above
# when I had specified `ARIMA(y)` without `x1`
fit.yx1 %>% pull(arima) %>% map(c('fit', 'par'))
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 x1        1.56     0.787      1.98  0.0712
# 
# [[2]]
# NULL
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 1 × 5
# term  estimate std.error statistic p.value
# <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
# 1 x1       -1.07     0.625     -1.71   0.139

# the following is to create a tibble with one row for each group
# and a tibble for each group, to be used in `. %>% model(arima=ARIMA(<my formula>))`
# though I don't know how to continue this approach and, basically, say
# -ARIMA(y~x1+x2) for group aa,
# -ARIMA(y~x2) for group bb,
# -ARIMA(y~x1) for group cc
# in a tidy way.
# But, also, I don't think this is even the right approach. 
# `fable::ARIMA()` was intended to be used once, for the entire dataset, with
# all series. It wasn't intended to be called once for each series, here, that
# being 3 times, once for each of series groups aa, bb, cc
dat %>%
  as_tibble %>%
  group_by(group) %>% summarise(across(x1:x2, \(.x) any(.x!=0))) %>% ungroup() %>%
  pivot_longer(cols=x1:x2, names_to='x', values_to='keep') %>%
  inner_join(
    dat %>% 
      as_tibble() %>% 
      pivot_longer(cols=x1:x2, names_to='x', values_to='value'),
    by=join_by(group, x)
  ) %>%
  filter(keep) %>% select(-keep) %>% 
  nest(data=-group) %>%
  mutate(data=map(data, \(.dat) pivot_wider(.dat, names_from=x, values_from=value) %>% 
                    as_tsibble(index=idx))) -> dat.series

dat.series
# # A tibble: 3 × 2
# group data             
# <chr> <list>           
#   1 aa    <tbl_ts [12 × 4]>
#   2 bb    <tbl_ts [6 × 3]> 
#   3 cc    <tbl_ts [6 × 3]> 

dat.series$data
# [[1]]
# # A tsibble: 12 x 4 [1]
# idx       y    x1    x2
# <int>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1 -0.560      0     0
# 2     2 -0.230      0     0
# 3     3  1.56       1     0
# 4     4  0.0705     0     0
# 5     5  0.129      0     0
# 6     6  1.72       0     0
# 7     7  0.461      0     0
# 8     8 -1.27       0     0
# 9     9 -0.687      0     0
# 10    10 -0.446      0     1
# 11    11  1.22       0     0
# 12    12  0.360      0     0
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tsibble: 6 x 3 [1]
# idx      y    x2
# <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     7  0.401     0
# 2     8  0.111     0
# 3     9 -0.556     0
# 4    10  1.79      1
# 5    11  0.498     0
# 6    12 -1.97      0
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tsibble: 6 x 3 [1]
# idx      y    x1
# <int>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1  0.701     0
# 2     2 -0.473     0
# 3     3 -1.07      1
# 4     4 -0.218     0
# 5     5 -1.03      0
# 6     6 -0.729     0

